# Windows XP Personalized Start Menu: how long until a program is hidden?

Tags: windows-xp, start-menu

Yes, at work we're still on Windows XP. Our Start Menu is also forced to be the Classic Windows 2000-style that hides your programs. So my question is: how long is it until a program is hidden from the Start Menu if you don't launch it from there? Is there a registry setting to control it?

Comment: Don't worry, I don't think XP (SP3) will be end-of-lifed until 2014. Still, interesting question.

Comment: To be honest I'm trying to see if I can get the Programs menu completely empty. For the programs I launch regularly I use the run command, creating a shortcut if it's not already in the PATH.